# select date in filemaker over odbc

Tags: php, mysql, filemaker

i try to select on PHPMyAdmin a date Field over odbc to update Date Field on FileMaker. But i´m getting an error:
Connection established.PHP Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:15): An expression contains incompatible data types.There is an error in the syntax of the query., SQL state HY000

this is my code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("DSN=server;Database=MyDatabase;UID=odbc;PWD=1234", "odbc", "1234");
if ($conn)
    echo "\nConnection established.";
else
    die("\nConnection could not be established.");

$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT ID_MH, MyDate FROM MyTable WHERE MyField LIKE '8'");
```

MyDate is an Date Format and i think "MyDate" should be converted into string with "strval".

But how?

Thanks!

Comment: check the like pattern here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: sorry Fortune but i thought MyDate and not MyField!

Comment: Well, what type of field is `MyField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to both @fortune and @michael.hor257k

There is nothing wrong with myDate field - you are just selecting it.

The problem is with your WHERE clause

If you use LIKE you need to add a pattern with a wildcard. See the link @fortune provided.

If you want to match records with MyField set to 8 you should use

```
WHERE MyField ='8'
```

But the error you are getting is most probably because you are matching with  string 8 and not a number 8 - this happened when you single quoted the number.
So MyField has to be the text field or you need to remove single quotes around 8